# Logging out from dashboard results in error 404: requested resource not available

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web

I need to logout from dahboard.jsp and go to index.jsp but while I'm clicking the logout button it is showing the error message like this,

> HTTP Status 404 - /Project/logout
>   type Status report
>   message /Project/logout
>   description The requested resource (/Project/logout) is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

the dashboard.jsp and the servlets login and logout are posted below, what might be the error in that.

**dashboard.jsp**

```
<div class="ends">
    <form action="logout" method="post" >
        <input type="submit" value="logout">
    </form>
</div>
```

**servlet page login   login.java**

```
package com.signin;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import com.db.DBCon;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class login
 */
public class login extends HttpServlet { 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String uid=request.getParameter("uid");
        String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd");


        try {
            DBCon dbc = new DBCon();
            if(dbc.validateLogin(uid, pwd))
            {
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("userid",uid);

                response.sendRedirect("dashboard.jsp");
            }
            else
                out.println("<center><h3>Sign in Failed!</h3><br><a href='index.jsp'>Go to Sign up page</a></center>");
            dbc.closeCon();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

**logout.java**

```
package com.signin;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;   
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class logout
 */
public class logout extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        session.removeAttribute("userid");
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `web.xml` file whether you map your **logout class** correctly. The issue may be there. Otherwise share the full error description and web.

Comment: Thank you buddy, the logout class was missing in web.xml